# Automated Testing Against SIte Created Via Google Web Toolkit

Tags: gwt, selenium, webdriver

I've moved onto a team who generate their site using Google Web Toolkit and we are looking at introducing automated testing. My initial thoughts are using Webdriver but I know one of the main issues are that due to Google Web Toolkit creating dynamic id's for the fields it becomes a bit of a nightmare.

I've read that you can assign ID's some how for when it is in dev/test mode but before I suggest this to the team (due to re-work being required to introduce it) whether there is a better way to handle dynamic id's within Webdriver itself or whether an alternative tool like sahi works any better?

Comment: Hi. If the Id's are the only concern and are dynamic then you can handle this with Xpath in webdriver. Not sure of other tools.

Comment: There are many other ways than an ID that you can select an element. XPath being one of them as Vinay mentioned. I suggest trying out Selenium for yourself so you can understand how actions are automated.

Comment: I've used selenium webdriver before extensively before in my previous job and I find the idea of falling back on XPaths or CSS as being a little fiddly as I'm not sure if its a little above the reach of some of the other testers.

Comment: Upvoted your question for mentioning SAHI which seems to be an interesting alternative for automated testing. It offers a GUI to record the test cases, which makes creating them less tedious!

Comment: Note that the Firefox plugin Selenium IDE can record test cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you really start from the scratch, then I can only recommend [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) framework which is used for in-container testing (you don't have to use mocks for your EJB and CDI beans in your tests), it has a plenty of useful extension

- [Drone](http://arquillian.org/guides/functional_testing_using_drone/) - makes functional testing with Selenium much more easier, especially together with [Graphene](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/Home) which adds many more functionality to WebDriver API so you don't to repeat yourself in the tests all the time
- [GWT](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-gwt) extension will help you with testing your server side GWT code

Also note that you can use `JQuery` locators (aka Sizzle) thans to Graphene which will make locating your elements little bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using XPath as much as possible. You don't want your test to be broken by the first CSS change.

You can use [UIObject.ensureDebugId("meaningfulId")](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html)

I often use it for Selenium testing. You have some doc about it in the [official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt.html).

Comment: Hi otonglet, I think I will need to raise about the use of the debugId as being the most manageable way to tracking down fields, as I don't want to worry about fields being moved around on a page and having to update tests.